# How to restore particular address from mnemonics created with ethereumjs-wallet

Tags: wallets, myetherwallet

Created a wallet instance using `fromMasterSeed` and `getWallet` functions from [ethereumjs/ethereumjs-wallet](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-wallet)

How can i restore the same using the mnemonics if I use the myetherwallet interface?

- I have created the seed using `bip39` standard Library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restore a wallet from mnemonic in myetherwallet (and mycrypto) but you have to be sure you're using the same derivation path (i.e. "m/44'/60'/0'/0/0").